# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic

Tags: flutter

The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

```
               Cita.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) : 
            this.fromMap(snapshot.data.call(), reference: snapshot.reference);
```

Comment: Can you show code to Cita and what's the object type of your snapshot. There's so much information missing. You could just try using `as` to cast the type

Answer (score 0):

using firebase, what will give you the `Map<String, dynamic>` is

```
snapshot.data.data()
```

in your case :

```
this.fromMap(snapshot.data.data(), reference: snapshot.reference);
```

Comment: The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Function'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data'.  


               Cita.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) 
                    :this.fromMap(snapshot.data.data(), reference: snapshot.reference);

Comment: @jmichelena try casting to a map: `this.fromMap(snapshot.data.data() as Map<String, Object?>, reference: snapshot.reference); `